# Element animates (slides) in and pushes element across

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have a `div` panel that is sliding out on click.

I have a title in the center of the page and what I'm looking for is when the panel slides out, it pushes the title along with it when it hits it, and when it clicks back it pulls the title back to the original position.

Is this possible?

I'm using Ajaxify which I've added the slide in/out transition to so unsure how useful it is, but here's an example:

```
transition_in = function () {
    if (!r(".panel-slide .close").length) {
        r(".panel-slide").animate({
            marginLeft: "20%"
        }, 1e3, "easeInOutCubic")
    }
};
```

Comment: mind creating a fiddle for us?

Comment: We can't do much unless and until u take the pains of posting the code in a fiddle or jsbin ...

Comment: I think what the other guys want to say is: We need more code.

Comment: You setting greater margin and if your divs are floating or static then it has to push the other elements around...

Comment: i guess your title has some property like text-align:center; you could achive your desired effect by position the title-text relative and add a margin in px to the left so it´s in the middle, then you could animate the margin-left to 0 simultanious with the panel-animation, i think it will look as you expect